# Polymer - can not click event outside of element to close itself

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.*

I had to write my own dropdown menu. I need to close the menu when the user clicks outside of the element. However, I am not able to catch the event when a user clicks outside of the element so I can close the menu.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I've studying paper-menu-button which closes paper-listbox when I click outside the element.... but I don't see anywhere where it catches that event https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu-button/blob/master/paper-menu-button.js#L311

```
<dom-module id="sp-referrals-reservations-dropdown">
  <template>
    <style include="grid-dropdown-styles">


    </style>

    <div id="dropdown" class="grid-dropdown">
        <paper-listbox>

          <div class="grid-dropdown-item">Convert to stay</div>
          <div class="grid-dropdown-item">Cancel reservation</div>
          <div class="grid-dropdown-item">Delete reservation</div>

        </paper-listbox>
    </div>


  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'sp-referrals-reservations-dropdown',

        behaviors: [Polymer.IronControlState],

        properties: {
        },

        listeners: {
          'tap': '_close',
          'click': '_close',
          'blur': '_close',
          'focusout': '_close',
          'focusChanged': '_close',
          'focus-changed': '_close',
          'active-changed': '_close',
          'activeChanged': '_close',
          'iron-activate': '_close',
          'ironActivate': '_close',
        },

        open: function(e) {

        },

        _close: function() {
          console.log('aaa');
          this.$.dropdown.style.display = "none";
        },

      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Could you share more codes, your own dropdown code, how you click outside element?  etc.

Comment: It works just like paper-menu-button or paper-dropdown-menu. Same logic. However, because of unique circumstances I had to build my own element. The issue is, when I click outside this element I can not catch a `click` event to close it like paper-menu-button or paper-dropdown-menu does.

Comment: I am sorry to ask u again, I am trying to understand how you click outside element. here I illustrated the code. You can fork if you want to add something. https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/yrBZRw?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks for taking  the time to make that. I created a fork here https://codepen.io/dman777-the-sans/pen/XQWraQ?editors=1011. So if you click outside of the pink space, I need that click/blur event to be caught by the element `<sp-referrals-reservations-dropdown>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, will it be enough, but if you wrap the `sp-referrals-reservations-dropdown` element with a `parent-element` then you can listen to parent-element events same as its child.

```
 <parent-element></parent-element>

  <dom-module id="parent-element">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display:block;
          background:green;
          width:100%;
          height:100vh; }
      </style>

      <sp-referrals-reservations-dropdown id="spref"></sp-referrals-reservations-dropdown>
```

At parent's script:

```
Polymer({is:'parent-element', properties:{}, 
           listeners:{ 'tap': '_taped'},

           _taped:function(t){
             this.$.spref._close();
           }
          });
```

this `_taped` functions will call child's `_close` function. Hope its help.

- Incase of needed more. We can develop this.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/yrBZRw?editors=1011)

**EDIT**

Wrap your element into paper-dialog. And at `ready:function()` call

`this.$.dialog.open()`

Then when you `click` outside of the element. `paper-dialog` will close automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this Monday. But it would be correct to catch that event from the element itself. Any ideas on how Polymer did this with `paper-menu-button' where when you click outside the paper-listbox disappears?

Comment: @dman ,I have another idea, that wrap your element into `paper-dialog`. And at `ready:function()` call `this.$.dialog.open();`   ...See the `Demo` link

Comment: Instead of the above, I got it to work by setting on-focused-changed from the button that opens it and closing it from the outside. But since your answer would also work I marked it. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, you weren't able to get this to work because custom elements don't listen for events outside of their own encapsulation unless you explicitly wire them up to do so... and if you do so, you can't use Polymer's built-in event handling.

So something like this would work:

```
// Insert this somewhere it'll get run once attached to the DOM
// This line keeps clicks within your element from closing the dropdown
this.shadowroot.addEventListener('click', (event) => { event.stopPropagation(); });
// And this listens for any click events that made it up to body, and closes the element
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', this._close);
```

Or, at least, that's what I think was going on. The polymer elements either did it by binding to a different event (blur?) or by having the parent element trigger an event on click that told the child element to close.